# Finding number of 10 digit numbers

Tags: combinatorics

A ten-digit number is to be made using the digits from the set $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ such that the difference between any two consecutive digits is either $1$ or $-1$. How many such numbers can be made?

Comment: Just an idea: you could also view each number as a stepping stone in a row, provided you cannot start at 0. Then, you might be able to categorize it in terms of left and right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is to count the number of numbers that follow your constraints *allowing* leading zeroes. You can modify it easily to disallow them, if necessary.

---

Let $A_n$ be the number of $n$-digit numbers that follow your rules and end with $0$ or $4$.

Let $B_n$ be the number of $n$-digit numbers that follow your rules and end with $1$ or $3$.

Let $C_n$ be the number of $n$-digit numbers that follow your rules and end with $2$.

---

Since the only $1$-digit numbers we consider are $0,1,2,3$, and $4$, we have:

$$A_1=2$$

$$B_1=2$$

$$C_1=1$$

Now we can write $A_2$, $B_2$, and $C_2$ in terms of the above values:

$$A_2 = B_1 = 2$$

$$B_2 = A_1+2C_1 = 4$$

$$C_2 = B_1 = 2$$

This agrees with the eight possibilities for two-digit numbers:

$$01,10,12,21,23,32,34,43$$

---

More generally, we can write $A_{n+1}$, $B_{n+1}$, and $C_{n+1}$ recursively:

$$A_{n+1} = B_n$$

$$B_{n+1} = A_n+2C_n$$

$$C_{n+1} = B_n$$

This should be enough for you to find the number of $10$-digit strings as

$$A_{10}+B_{10}+C_{10}$$

---

I wrote a bit of code to find that

$$A_{10} = C_{10} = 162$$

$$B_{10} = 324$$

This is a total of $\boxed{648}$ ten-digit numbers.